# Is it possible to multiply an equation by a variable in GEKKO?

Tags: gekko

I am trying to solve an MINLP problem where I define some constraints between variables by setting them to a dummy variable with a lower and upper bound. After that, I try to enable or disable those constraints by multiplying the equation by a binary variable belonging to special ordered set. I kind of assumed the multiplication would carry through the equation, however I am getting the following error (with modified variable names):

```
----------------------------------------------------------------
 APMonitor, Version 1.0.0
 APMonitor Optimization Suite
 ----------------------------------------------------------------


 --------- APM Model Size ------------
 Each time step contains
   Objects      :  7
   Constants    :  0
   Variables    :  81
   Intermediates:  205
   Connections  :  57
   Equations    :  302
   Residuals    :  47

 @error: Model Expression
 *** Error in syntax of function string: Invalid element: dummy_var=(function_1

Position: 23
((binary_var)*(dummy_var=(function_1-function_2)
               ?
```

Any help is greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Multiply both sides of the equation to activate or deactivate it with the binary variable.

```py
m.Equation(b*y==b*x)
```

Here is a complete example with an `m.sos1()` variable.

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(-5)
y = m.Var()
b = m.sos1([0,1])
m.Equation(b*y==b*x)
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

If there is a condition that leads to an ON / OFF condition for an equation then use the `m.if3()` statement such as:

```py
from gekko import GEKKO
m = GEKKO()
x = m.Param(-1)
y = m.Var(1)
b = m.if3(x,0,1)
m.Equation(b*y==b*x)
m.solve()
print(x.value[0],y.value[0])
```

Changing the value to `x = m.Param(1)` re-activates the equation. You may also want to try slack variables that are typically much more efficient for logical conditions.

Comment: Thanks John, the issue I am coming across is that as part of my program I set up all of the equations before I create the SOS variables. In fact, I think doing it that will cause issues because I have already built the equations in the model before trying to multiply them by the binary variable. I think I will have to re-work it so that I can track the SOS vars and apply them to rhs and lhs of the equations.

Comment: Just wanted to drop a quick note here, I needed to create my own slack variable and multiply it by the SOS variable instead of having one automatically generated for inequality equations. If one is automatically generated, it is not bound by the binary SOS variable and I think it ends up getting set to zero.